# spark bugs fixed by jira task

Tags: apache-spark, jira, cloudera

i'm using Cloudera 5.11 with spark 2.2.0,

I have a question regarding the use of spark issues, resolved in jira task.

If I'm facing a bug that resolved by a jira task, how can I apply this fix to my environment?

Do I need to compile the spark source code? Or should I wait for Cloudera support this patch.

link for [jira issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-24867?filter=allopenissues)

Thanks for advise,
Maor

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you would have used Spark2 service in Cloudera Manager provided by Cloudera. If this is the case then even though the issue is fixed in specific version of Spark, it might not be available to you due to lack of updated binary from Cloudera. Probably, there would be a way to find out whether Cloudera has already consumed the fix while preparing the Spark2 parcel at their end.